# Big O notation on the log factorial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

For the computation of the log factorial, i.e., $\log(n!)$, is the Big(O) run time for this $n\log(n)$? How can this be assumed graphically?

***Update: How does the sum of $\log(n!)$ work then? I.e., the sum of log Factorial?

Comment: The sum comes from log rules.  See my answer below.

Comment: I see the properties of the log rule, but is sum(log(n!)) then O(n *log(n)) as well??

Comment: No.  Note that $$\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)=\mathcal O(n\log(n))$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that:

$$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$

Thus,

$$\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)<\sum_{k=1}^n\log(n)=n\log(n)$$

A lower bound may be done with Riemann sums:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)>\int_1^n\log(x)\ dx=n\log(n)-n+1$$

Here's the graphical component:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\log(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)$$ 
Can you figure it out from here using properties of Big-$O$ notation? You'll find that the answer to your conjecture is a resounding yes; graphically, this is because $n^n$ is a decent estimator of $n! $. Look up Stirling Approximation for more detail

Comment: Yes I can. Specifically, is the run time of the log(n!) nlog(n) in bigO?

Comment: @NinaMcGyver yes. Notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n!)}{n\log(n)} = 1$

Comment: @NinaMcGyver graphically this is because $n^n$ is a decent estimator of $n! $. Look up Stirling Approximation for more detail

Comment: made an update above. Thanks

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Isn't Stirling approximation overkill for this?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes... but just take the simplest form of it and you're fine. Knowing the exact constants isn't important. This is more or less what you do in your post.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt even your answer  is overkill if you can take limits and already have the OP's conjecture for the record, as I point out in my comment above

Comment: Hm, now that I think about it, I feel like there should be different names to the approximations of the factorial.  Who's idea was it to name them all "Stirling's approximation"?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen :-/ Those limits aren't trivial though.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen $n^n$ is not a decent estimator of $n!$. Actually, we have $n! \in o(n^n)$.