# Sum(log(n!)) Big(O) notation and graphical properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

For the computation of the run time/big O notation of sum(log factorial), i.e., $\sum(\log(n!))$, is the Big(O) run time for this $O(n^2)$?

Why is that?

Comment: For more context: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152256/big-o-notation-on-the-log-factorial

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, this question is a bit modified and I looked at the other one as well, but my question got ignored

Comment: This needs a lot of clarification. Do you want some big $O$ value for $\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k!)$? $\sum\log(n!)$ is meaningless.

Comment: I want the sum from k = 1 to n Log(k!).....i.e.,     # Return the sum of log_factorial(i) for i in 1..n

Comment: @NinaMcGyver I am just saying it's additional context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Yes--I updated it above. Please advise